Azure functions v2 python deployed through terraform but not showing in portal?
I am deploying a python azure function v2 via terraform when I deploy through visual studio code it deploys succesfully, however through terraform all supposedly deploys successfully, however the function app (blob trigger) does not show up in the azure portal.
Any advice on the matter would be appreciated

Have you tried any code so far? @Jimmy3421

yes I have deployed code to the Azure function via visual studio code and Github / Terraform

Can you share the code deployed so far! @Jimmy3421

You can use below code to deploy function app function python v2 with blob trigger using terraform.
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
subscription_id="xxxx"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name     = "pyrgp"
  location = "WestEurope"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storage" {
  name                     = "funcstoragenew"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}


resource "azurerm_service_plan" "asp" {
  name                = "newservice-plan"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "Y1"
}


resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "function_app" {
  name                       = "jahfunctionapp"
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  service_plan_id            = azurerm_service_plan.asp.id
  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.storage.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.storage.primary_access_key
  site_config {
  }
  app_settings = {
    FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME = "python"
    AzureWebJobsStorage      = azurerm_storage_account.storage.primary_connection_string
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_container" "example" {
  name                  = "sample-container"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.storage.name
  container_access_type = "private"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "function" {
  name                   = "python-function.zip"
  storage_account_name   = azurerm_storage_account.storage.name
  storage_container_name = azurerm_storage_container.example.name
  type                   = "Block"
  source                 = "python-functionzipped.zip"
}
resource "azurerm_function_app_function" "function" {
  name           = "BlobTriggerFunction"
  function_app_id = azurerm_linux_function_app.function.id
  language = "Python"
  depends_on = [azurerm_storage_blob.function_zip]
  config_json = jsonencode({
    scriptFile = "init.py"
    "bindings" = [
      {
        "authLevel" = "function"
        "direction" = "in"
        "methods" = [
          "get",
          "post",
        ]
        "name" = "blob"
        "type" = "blobTrigger"
        "path"      = "${azurerm_storage_container.example.name}/{blobName}"
        "connection" = "AzureWebJobsStorage"
      }
    ]
  })
}


Reference: azurerm_function_app_function
